# Can't override libpng15 with newer install

Tags: linux, uninstallation, yum, libpng

I've downloaded and installed libpng from http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html, which is version 1.6.16, following their simple instructions:

- ./configure
- ./make check
- sudo ./make install

It runs with everything successful, and says it's been installed. However, after doing this I still read:

```
$ libpng-config --cflags --ldflags
-I~/anaconda/include/libpng15
-L~/anaconda/lib -lpng15
```

This is breaking other builds and installs, which sometimes detect 15 while requiring 16. How can I fix this?

Fedora Linux 20 x 64

Comment: Where is your libpng-config?  Type "type libpng-config" to see.  If you wanted libpng16 to go in ~anaconda/ then use ./configure --prefix=~anaconda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want libpng16 to go in your $HOME/ then, in your libpng directory, run

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
./make
./make install
```

This will install png*.h in $HOME/include/, libpng-config in $HOME/bin/,
and the library itself in $HOME/lib/.

If you want to put it in some other directory where you don't have write permission, the final command is

```
sudo ./make install
```

Comment: Just a few fixes: please specify that this is to be done in the libpng folder, and that --prefix requires the full path to the destination (won't work with ~/)